# How to get changelog info for pip upgrade-able modules

Tags: python, pip, python-module

If I do

```
 pip list --outdated
```

I get a list of upgrade-able modules. For example:

```
Package            Version    Latest   Type
------------------ ---------- -------- -----
aiofiles           22.1.0     23.1.0   wheel
anyio              3.6.2      3.7.0    wheel
attrs              22.2.0     23.1.0   wheel
beautifulsoup4     4.11.2     4.12.2   wheel
comm               0.1.2      0.1.3    wheel
Cython             0.29.33    0.29.35  wheel
[...]
```

Is there any way to get the changelog or relevant release notes for the new versions that would be installed?  I would like to get these programmatically, ideally from the command line if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. The wheels don't usually have any changelog in them, just a top-level README embedded in the [Description](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#description) field (and even that is optional).

Your best bet would be to check at the [Project-URL](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#project-url-multiple-use)(s) to try and find a changelog, but this would be difficult to do programmatically, and not all projects even bother to keep a changelog.

Comment: This is a shame.   I wonder if getting a changelog if it exists is possible programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in programatic way to retrieve changelogs.

The PEPs defining "Metadata for Python Software Packages" ([241](https://peps.python.org/pep-0241/), [314](https://peps.python.org/pep-0341/), [345](https://peps.python.org/pep-0345/), [566](https://peps.python.org/pep-0566/)) don't define anything for changelogs. Given there is no standard location, there is no guaranteed place to find it for any given package. However, there are many *common* places to look.

The [changelogs](https://github.com/pyupio/changelogs) project attempts to do this. It's not a perfect solution as noted in the readme:

> When trying to get a changelog for a given package, there are a bunch of problems:
>
> - There is no central place to store a changelog. If a project has a changelog, it's most likely somewhere in the git repo at all kinds of different places. This makes it hard to find.
> - The package index meta data often has no direct link to the git repo. This makes the repo hard to find.
> - There is no changelog standard. Everyone uses a different approach. This makes it hard to parse.
>
> This project is trying to solve this by:
>
> - first querying the package vendor for package meta data like the homepage or docs URL.
> - if the meta data doesn't contain a valid URL to a repo, visit all available URLs and scrape them to find one.
> - if there is a valid repo URL, visit the repo and look for possible changelogs like Changes.txt, NEWS.md or history.rst.
> - fetch the content and somewhat try to parse it.